# SQL Server to server synchronization

Tags: sql-server

I want to synchronize my local SQL Server database to the shared hosting SQL Server database from Mochahost.com. What will be required to do this? Or is there any easy way to synchronize this SQL Server database with a MySQL database? Please give me suggestions.

Comment: Hi Humza, is it always local->mochahost.com?  or does mochahost.com ever have newer records?

Comment: just local to mochahost.com :) nothing newer will be added on hosting mochahost.com

Comment: what you are asking for is merge replication.  Look here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337473.aspx.  For reference, the publisher is the local, the subscriber is the mochahost.com server.  Give this a throw, and see if you can do this.  It's pretty simple, just time intenstive.

Comment: MySQL to SQL Server replication? onto a remote host? First problem is the connection to the remote SQL Server, second is how to convert all the data types, indexes... etc... SSIS could handle all that, no simple task.

Comment: @RicardoC sir i have mssql on local also and mssql on remote also but whenever i try to become subscriber on remote host sql server says you have to use server name instead of server address and i'm not able to resolve this problem

Comment: @HumzaMalik You may want to consider changing your question then. I suggest: "SQL Server replication to server outside the domain problem". Then give details of your setup, Then give details of your attempted solutions, then give details of the error. oh, and remove that MySQL from it.

Comment: I've tried to replicate local mssql database to remote one :) but when i try to become subscriber of local publication remote sql server responds that use real servename "WDB1" but to connect that server i use "wdb1.my-hosting-panel.com" as server name . That's the reason for problem

Answer (score 0):

[SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org) supports replication to and from MSSQL Server and MySQL.  There is an open source version as well as a supported professional version at [Jumpmind](http://www.jumpmind.com).

Comment: Is there any proper prior knowledge i need to use that ? i tried that i was not able to use that properly any guidance for that will be appreciated